How to report bugs in Google Maps walking directions?
A number of times now I've gotten directions from Google Maps that include a walking component over an entirely impossible area (e.g., a narrow stretch of the ocean, over a wall onto a restricted military base, etc.). This entirely bungles the routing, because every displayed route tries to make use of this impossible bottleneck.
I'd like to report a bug to fix this, but none of the reporting options seem to apply. Using the web application in a desktop browser, "Edit the map" leads to options like Fix an address, Missing place, Add or fix a road, and Wrong information about a business. None of these seem to apply to these impossible off-road walking directions.
What's the best way to report a bug in Google Maps off-road walking directions?

It's a bit unintuitive, but it looks like currently the best path to submitting a problem like this in the web app is: Menu > Edit the map > Your opinions about Maps > Report an issue > Travel to a destination > Describe your issue > Next > Send.
(Note that currently the "Upload screenshot" option does not seem to work, and the report fails to send if there is any screenshot attached; so skip that and describe how to replicate the problem in text.)
